# React Redux - Access state between two components

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have two React Components, Header (with input) and Search.

How I can access 'userInput' from Search Component?

Header Component

```
  import React, {useState} from 'react';
    
    const Header = () => {
    
      const [userInput, setUserInput] = useState('');
      const inputchangehandler = (event) => {
        setUserInput(event.target.value)
      }
    
      return (
       <div className="header">
       <input type="text" name="nome" onChange={inputchangehandler} value={userInput} />
       </div>
      )
    }
```

Search Component

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'; 
 
const Search = () => {

  //const { word } = useParams();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const word = useSelector(state => state.userInput);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(userInput); 
    dispatch(fetchAsyncMoviesSearch(word ));
  }, [dispatch, word])

  return (
    <div>
      <MovieListing />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: dispatch an action to store the input when the input changes and access it using `useSelector` in Search component

Comment: Updated code with useSelector but doesn't work. I'm sorry but I'm a beginner with react. thanks for support

Comment: @mustaine I wrote an elaborate answer below you can check it out

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Redux for state sharing between components, it's best to have a Redux action that dispatches the `userInput` to store from `Header` component when user types in the search, then access `userInput` from `Search` component later using `useSelector()`.

The core idea is [dispatching an action](https://redux.js.org/api/store#dispatchaction) that contains user input value to Redux store.

Your custom `updateSearchInput` Redux action can look like this:

```js
// assuming that you have it in ./customReduxActions.js file
// ...

export const updateSearchInput = (keyword) => ({
  type: 'update-search-input',
  payload: keyword,
});

// ...
```

Then your Redux store needs to be able to process this action:

```js
switch (action.type) {
  // ... other actions

  case 'update-search-input':
    return {
      ...state,
      userInput: action.payload
    };

  // ... other actions
}
```

After this, when you access `state.userInput` using `useSelector()` you should be able to get the input value from Redux store across components.

Your `Header` component then can look like this:

```
    // Your custom action written above
    import { updateSearchInput } from './customReduxActions';

    const Header = () => {

      const dispatch = useDispatch();
      const userInput = useSelector(state => state.userInput);
      
      const inputChangeHandler = (event) => {
        const keyword = event.target.value;
        
        // this dispatch() call is most important
        dispatch(updateSearchInput(keyword));
      };
    
      return (
       <div className="header">
         <input
           type="text"
           name="nome"
           onChange={inputChangeHandler}
           value={userInput}
         />
       </div>
      )
    }
```

Your `Search` component remains the same with no changes:

```
const Search = () => {

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  // access state.userInput from Redux store as expected behavior
  const word = useSelector(state => state.userInput);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchAsyncMoviesSearch(word));
  }, [dispatch, word])

  return (
    <div>
      <MovieListing />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are already using redux, I think it is easier to handle the userInput with it instead of useState in this situation.

So you can create the userInput redux state and the setUserInput redux action, as well. Something like this:

Header component

```
const Header = () => {

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const userInput = useSelector(state => state.userInput)

  const inputchangehandler = (event) => {
    dispatch(setUserInput(event.target.value))
  }

  return (
    <div className="header">
    <input type="text" name="nome" onChange={inputchangehandler} value={userInput} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Search component

```
const Search = () => {

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const word = useSelector(state => state.userInput);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchAsyncMoviesSearch(word ));
  }, [dispatch, word])

  return (
    <div>
      <MovieListing />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: I get 'setUserInput' is not defined

Comment: you need to create the action and import it as you did with the fetchAsyncMoviesSearch.

Comment: here you can see an example to follow: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-repl-forked-p8dudp?file=/src/index.js

Comment: I'm looking your example, why 'setUserInput' from Search component is created but never used?

Comment: Oh, the setUserInput there was useless, my mistake. It is being called and used only in the Header component